# v4l2 not accepting configuration until after boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, alpine-linux, openrc, v4l

I'm using v4l2 on my Raspberry Pi 3A+ with Alpine Linux but the official Raspberry Pi Kernel/Firmware installed. I'm trying to have my Raspi-Camera autostart and serve a livestream through mjpg-streamer, and this is my attempt so far:

**/etc/init.d/mjpg-streamer**

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run
command="/usr/local/bin/mjpg.sh"
command_background="yes"
pidfile="/run/mjpg-streamer.pid"
depend() {
        need net
}
```

**/usr/local/bin/mjpg.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
chgrp video /dev/video0
chmod g+rw /dev/video0

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=1440,height=1080,pixelformat=3
chpst -u mjpg:video -- mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www/" -i "input_uvc.so -r 1440x1080 -d /dev/video0 -f 15"
```

However, upon boot this doesn't work as expected. Neither the resolution nor the pixelformat are being set correctly, and what I get on the livestream is a bad quality stream with visible pixels and very bad colors.

As soon as the Pi is started, I can ssh to it, restart above unit, and get a perfect quality livestream the way I expected. So I assume that there is something missing as a dependency that needs to be started before I can set v4l2 options and start mjpg-streamer. I tried to place a `sleep` command in that shell script, but to no avail.

What can I do to have this script work correctly on autostart and not only when invoked afterwards?